# Сборка элементов в Map

Tags: java, строки

Нужно собрать переданный стрим чисел в мапу, где ключ сам элемент, а значение это его квадрат.

Мой код:

```
public class CollectToMap {
    public static Map<Integer, Integer> collect(Stream<Integer> data) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> result = Set.of(data).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> v));

        return result;
    } 
}
```

Мой тест:

```
public class CollectToMapTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Integer> data = List.of(2, 3);
        Map<Integer, Integer> expect = Map.of(
                2, 4,
                3, 9
        );
        Map<Integer, Integer> result = CollectToMap.collect(data.stream());
        assertEquals(expect, result);
    }
}
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: @Danil Apsadikov, лучше не форматировать так код, что все символы `>` слетают: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/780201

Comment: @insolor Хорошо, заметил только после отправки )

Comment: У вас повторяется одна и та же подобная ошибка: вы зачем-то оборачиваете каждый раз входной список/стрим в отдельную коллекцию, для которой снова применяете `.stream()`.  Таким образом `Set.of(data).stream()` возвращает `Stream<Stream<Integer>>`.  Представленный код вообще не компилируется, возникает ошибка: `error: incompatible types: inference variable K has incompatible bounds`

Comment: что нужно исправить в коде чтобы код компилировался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понял, вы забыли `v * v`

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> collect(Stream<Integer> data) {
    return data.collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, v -> v * v));
}
```

Comment: нет. дело не в этом коде - v * v

Comment: Тогда не совсем понял в чем вопрос. Я не много изменил код и ваш тест мой код прошел. Уточните проблему

Comment: @DanilApsadikov, вы радикально изменили код, убрав излишнее оборачивание входного стрима в `Set` при помощи `Set.of`, поэтому ваш вариант успешно скомпилировался и прошел тест.

Comment: @DanilApsadikov все разобрался. Спасибо!